# Magento 2 How To Add Custom Text After All Prices

Tags: magento2, price, format, event-observer

I tried to add custom text after all prices that appears in magento 2.

For this I tried to do in 2 ways:

1) I tried to modify function `getPrice` from `module-catalog\Model\Product.php` like this:

```
public function getPrice()
    {
        if ($this->_calculatePrice || !$this->getData(self::PRICE)) {
           return $this->getPriceModel()->getPrice($this)."some text";
        } else {
            return $this->getData(self::PRICE);
        }
    }
```

but this is not working. If I add some **int** value this will work on every page, othewise is show 0.

if I will do this: `return $this->getPriceModel()->getPrice($this)* 100;` this will work.

I tried to add this custom text on "currency_display_options_forming" event like this:

```
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $baseCode = $observer->getEvent()->getBaseCode();
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();


        if ($baseCode === 'EUR') { // change currency symbol position to Right with EUR
            $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::RIGHT)."some text";

        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is also not working.

Does anyone have a good idea how to do that?

Maybe I should find function that format this value from `getPrice` function? if yes, is somebody that know where I can find this function?

Comment: How to add "some text" before the symbol?

Answer (score 3):

You can use magento's plugin functionality
Create `di.xml` file in `etc > frontend > di.xml`

Put below code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" shared="false">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_product_list_text" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ProductListPlugin" disabled="false" sortOrder="999" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create plugin file

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class ProductListPlugin {

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @return string
     */
    public function afterGetProductPrice($subject, $result, $product)
    {
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
        $logger->info($result);

        $subscriptionTextHTML = '<div class="custom_text"><span>It will display</span></div>';

        return $result.$subscriptionTextHTML;
    }

}
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have attached to core module code

1) Solution first

> module-catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php

```
public function getProductPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $priceRender = $this->getPriceRender();

    $price = '';
    if ($priceRender) {
        $price = $priceRender->render(
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            [
                'include_container' => true,
                'display_minimal_price' => true,
                'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                'list_category_page' => true
            ]
        );
    }

    return $price.'test';
}
```

2) Solution second

> module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phml

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_product).'test' ?>
```

Hope this will help you.